# Convert Json String to List in Android

Tags: java, android, json

```
    strResponse = {"GetCitiesResult":["1-Vizag","2-Hyderbad","3-Pune","4-Chennai","9-123","11-Rohatash","12-gopi","13-Rohatash","14-Rohatash","10-123"]}

 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);

            // get LL json object
 String json_LL = json.getJSONObject("GetCitiesResult").toString();
```

Now i want to convert the json string to List in andriod

Comment: That is not valid Java code. Did you mean to say that variable `strResponse` has the value `{"GetCitiesResult":["1-Vizag","2-Hyderbad","3-Pune","4-Chennai","9-123","11-Rohatash","12-gopi","13-Rohatash","14-Rohatash","10-123"]}`?

Comment: Gson might help you

Comment: please make sure  the what response you are getting strResponse is incorrect...

Comment: Why do you call `getJSONObject("GetCitiesResult")` when you know that value of `GetCitiesResult` is an ***array***? Try `getJSONArray("GetCitiesResult")` instead. And **do not** convert it to a `String`.

Comment: If you like java streams have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure your response String is correct format, if it is, then try this:

```
try {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("GetCitiesResult");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        list.add(array.getString(i));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply using Gson library you can convert json response to pojo class.

Copy the json string to create pojo structure using this link: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
GetCitiesResult citiesResult = gson.fromJson(responseString, GetCitiesResult.class);
```

It will give the `GetCitiesResult` object inside that object you get a list of your response like

```
public List<String> getGetCitiesResult() {
    return getCitiesResult;
}
```

Call only `citiesResult.getGetCitiesResult();` it will give a list of cities.

You can also use this library `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code did the trick

```
List<String> list3 = json.getJSONArray("GetCitiesResult").toList()
                              .stream()
                              .map(o -> (String) o)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
list3.forEach(System.out::println);
```

And printed:

```
1-Vizag
2-Hyderbad
3-Pune
4-Chennai
9-123
11-Rohatash
12-gopi
13-Rohatash
14-Rohatash
10-123
```

Answer (score 0):

below is code:

```
 private void parse(String response) {
    try {

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetCitiesResult");

        for (int i=0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++){
            stringList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }
Log.d ("asd", "--------"+ stringList);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Output is when print list :

```
 --------[1-Vizag, 2-Hyderbad, 3-Pune, 4-Chennai, 9-123, 11-Rohatash, 12-gopi, 13-Rohatash, 14-Rohatash, 10-123]
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok you must know first something about **JSON**

Json object is be  `{// some attribute}`

Json Array is be  `[// some attribute]`

Now You have

```
{"GetCitiesResult":["1-Vizag","2-Hyderbad",
"3-Pune","4-Chennai","9-123","11-Rohatash",
"12-gopi","13-Rohatash","14-Rohatash","10-123"]}
```

That`s Means you have JSON array is **GetCitiesResult**

which have array of String

Now Try this

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray loadeddata = new JSONArray(obj.getString("GetCitiesResult")); 
                        for (int i = 0; i <DoctorData.length(); i++) {// what to do here}
```

where **data** is your String

Comment: Converting the already parsed JSON data to a string, just to parse it again, is a total waste of processing time.